# Insert a value to $form_state

Tags: forms, 8

```
    function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
      $form_state ['store_value'] =1;
      $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
      );


  return $form;
}
```

How to do this in drupal 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insert the the value in `$form_state`:

```
$form_state->set('store_value', 1);
```

And then later for example in `submitForm()`:

```
$value = $form_state->get('store_value');
```

Don't use getValue() or setValue(), because this is for submitted values.

If you are migrating more forms from D7 to D8, use this as reference:

[$form_state is now a classed object](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310411)

Comment: Correct, be aware of how form caching changed however, it might no longer behave the way you expect it to: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192402/is-it-still-possible-to-use-a-custom-attribute-for-a-form-e-g-formfoo/192464#192464

Comment: Good advice. It depends on what kind of data you store and what you want to do with it. Some things better work with a session, either to store all the data or in combination with form data.

Answer (score 0):

`$form_state` is a instance of [FormState](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/class/FormState/8.0.x) object, you need use `setValue($key, $value)` method to store values on it.

Check the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetValue/8.0.x) for additional info.

**From docs:**

> Parameters
>
> string|array $key: Values are stored as a multi-dimensional
>   associative array. If $key is a string, it will use $values[$key] =
>   $value. If $key is an array, each element of the array will be used as
>   a nested key. If $key = array('foo', 'bar') it will use
>   $values['foo']['bar'] = $value.
>
> mixed $value: The value to set.