# Save value in form with multiple instances in same page

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

This is my `buildForm` function:

```
class NewsletterForm extends FormBase {
  // ...
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $newsletter_list = NULL) {
    $form_state->set('newsletter_list', $newsletter_list);
    // ...
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $newsletter_list = $form_state->get('newsletter_list');
    // I save $newsletter_list and others values.
    // ...
  }
}
```

I pass this form to template, specifically in hook_preprocess_alter():

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($route != 'layout_builder.overrides.node.view') {
    $newsletter_list = $block->field_newsletter->value;
    $form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\MYMODULE\Form\NewsletterForm', $newsletter_list);
    $variables['newsletter_form'] = $form;
  }
}
```

When my template show me two same form (but two different value in `newsletter_list`) and I fill the second one, the line `$newsletter_list = $block->field_newsletter->value` takes the value of first form. Why does it that? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I use ajax submission.

Comment: Two different things to consider. 1) $form_state->set() in a form build https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192402/is-it-still-possible-to-use-a-custom-attribute-for-a-form-e-g-formfoo 2) multiple instances of a form https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223269/cannot-deal-with-multiple-iterations-of-same-form-on-one-page

Comment: The second link will be the relevant one. Each form requires a separate form ID.

Comment: The first one is equally important, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264407/form-storage-is-cleared-after-ajax-submission

Comment: I also use ajax submission :(

Comment: This link helped me https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/272176/26752